# Senchacmd did not find a system installed ruby runtime

Tags: bamboo, sencha-cmd

I have installed the rvm and ruby, and it's installed under `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby`, but when I run the build via bamboo, senchacmd it's failing by saying

```
Did not find a system installed ruby runtime
27-Feb-2020 11:31:41    Please install ruby for this platform and ensure that
27-Feb-2020 11:31:41    a ruby command compatible with 1.8 or 1.9 is available
27-Feb-2020 11:31:41    on the system path.
```

I come to know that senchacmd fail to load the ruby while building, and I have tried a couple of solutions which dint help much.

https://www.enovision.net/sencha-cmd-ruby-not-found/

Answer (score 0):

Search in your project file `.sencha/package/build.properties` and set in it path to your ruby

```
build.ruby.path=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
```